# How to match an npm package with another version if the default doesn't work?

Tags: npm

Using a React Redux Starter template, I saw that it is using

```
"react": "^0.14.3"
```

and if I `npm install --save country-data`, it would install:

```
"country-data": "0.0.31"
```

and this version of `country-data` doesn't work -- however, it can work with the current version of react version `15.4.2`.  So I am thinking to check the date of the release date of `react 0.14.3`, and use a version of `country-data` which is slightly before or after the release date of `react 0.14.3`

How can you check the release date of `react 0.14.3` and a list of release dates of the different versions of `country-data`, perhaps using `npm`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. The `npm view` command may be used for that. It show data about package in json format. For example to know info about 'react' package run:

```
npm view react
```

or only for release dates:

```
npm view react time
```

Also release date for some project may be found in its repo. For example git repo releases most time is tagged, so use `git tag`. If repo on github go to tab `releases`.